# Redirect ErrorDocuments based on Referrer?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, referrer

Is it possible, in .htaccess, to redirect ErrorDocument requests based on their referrer?

For example user requests http://domain.com/folder1/ [which is a 404] would it be possible to redirect that request to only if it came from domain.com to https://securedomain%{REQUEST_URI} or something similar...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot declare `ErrorDocument` directive conditionally based on the value of HTTP_REFERER field.

But using `RewriteRule` in conjunction with `RewriteCond` you could manually rewrite/point to the required file/url which will display an error page.